# Box position on bing design

Tags: css, resize, position

I want to reproduce a bit the bing.com design own my website.
I have a background img with

```
background-size: cover;
```

in order to have a beautiful resizing of the picture.

The problem is I want also to display as bing.com small boxes at specified position, and I want to keep this position even if the website is resized. I use absolute position with percentage, the problem is when I resize my website, the boxes moved a lot and they loose their desired position. How can I manage that in CSS (even in JS ?)

my code :
http://dahevos.free.fr/wip/design.html . I want that the small box must be set on the tron even if you resize the window

Comment: Provide a fiddle link where we can see your HTML and CSS code that you have done.

Comment: Yeah, sure : http://dahevos.free.fr/wip/design.html . I want that the small box must be set on the tron even if you resize the window

Comment: Rototo, what @NathanLee is talking about is a link to http://jsfiddle.net/ with your (relevant) code inserted, so that potential answer-ers can manipulate it themselves in the browser.  A link to your website is fine, but it's not as easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `block` which should be the parent of the `block` that is having a `position:absolute;` attribute. That parent `block` should have the `position:relative;` attribute. This should exist in order to keep the position of the absolute positioned elements intact even if the screen re-size takes place.

## for Instance,

```
<div style="position:relative;">
     <nav style="position:absolute;">&nbsp;</nav>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.